# Objective C - UITableViewCell crashing on scroll

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell with a method like this.

```
-(void) setupStore:(StoreModel *) store {
    self.title.text = store.title; // crash here when scrolling
}
```

So that method is called from within a UIViewController class that contains the UITableView.
Something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    [cell setupStore:[storesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    ...
}
```

That works when the table first loaded, but when I scroll the table, it crash with error EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

What could be causing that?

Please enlight.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: You're accessing an object that's been deallocated. Can you show us how/where you set the `storesArray` property?

Comment: Hey warrenm, here is how I set     storesArray. storesArray = [[[StoresLocations alloc] init] retain]; And storesArray is a property of the UIViewController. Doing an NSLog right before I call     [cell setupStore:[storesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; actually does give me a value. Thanks, Tee

Comment: [[[StoresLocations alloc] init] retain]; is already over-retaining, as alloc/init increase the reaitnCount with 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build your code with `NSZombieEnabled = YES` and report here what is happening. Give us the full error description.

http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16

Answer (score 0):

In general We will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when we are trying to use a released object.

So you can check whether you are using any released object.

As you have mentioned that `storesArray = [[[storesLocation alloc] init]retain];` there is no need to retain the object. Give a try by using this line

```
storesArray = [[storesLocation alloc] init];.
```

Also make sure that storemodel object exists by logging it in this method

```
-(void) setupStore:(StoreModel *) store
{
   NSLog(@"store model %@",store);
}
You can go through the link
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html